# Problemas al ejecutar .jar en MAC

Tags: java, jar

He programado una pequeña aplicación en un macbook air, con apache netbeans 12 y en el momento de crear el archivo .jar lo crea sin problemas. El problema viene en el momento de ejecutar siempre me sale un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He comprobado los errores de la consola y me informa del siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo el programa si se ejecuta desde la terminal con java -jar nombre.jar
No entiendo porque no funciona. Antes tenia una macbook pro y nunca tube ningún problema, siempre se ejecutaban a la primera.

Comment: a lo mejor necesita permisos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que finalmente he localizado el error. Comento por si a alguien le pasa algo parecido.
El problema creo que estava en que havia tres maquinas virtuales de java.
El Apache Netbeans utilizaba la ultima version de java, la 14.0.1 y al momento de ejecutar lo realizaba con la version 8.0.
He desinstalado todas las versiones de java dejando solo la ultima. Ahora de momento todo funciona correctamente.
Gracias Javier G.Raya por contestar.